# LoadError in Devise (Cannot load bcrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, windows-7-x64, bcrypt

So I'm having issues with creating users with Devise.
It's an issue with "bcrypt".

[Here is the error that's being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVeoc.png)

I looked at a few similar threads here and the solution was to install the bcrypt gem for Ruby. 
And so I went to rubygems.org and added the line in gem file then ran bundle install.

However, after that I try to run the server but it fails for some reason. Server won't start. Here is the error I received in GitBash:

```
Zak@ZAKARIA ~/Desktop/Work/raddit (add_users)
$ rails s
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependen
cies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcry
pt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcry
pt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:91:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:86:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:75:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:75:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:
in `require'
        from c:/Users/Zak/Desktop/Work/raddit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/
commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/
commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/
commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/
commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/
commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.
rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

NOTE: Before adding the gem, the server would run just fine.

Also here is my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'

group :development, :test do
   gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ajeferson's asnwer.

This thread has the solution: github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to set the explicitly bcrypt in your Gemfile. Devise already includes bcrypt as a runtime dependency. Try to remove the bcrypt gem from your Gemfile, run `bundle update` and the restart your server. That worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but I saw several answers here saying to re install bcrypt. Anyway I'll try your suggestion update with the results.

Comment: Tried it. No luck. Same issue. Also I had the same issue with another app I was working on previously (However I thought it could have been another issue since that app had a lot of defects)

Comment: Have you changed something about the hashing encrypt algorithm in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`?

Comment: Also, check this thread https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Comment: No, I haven't touched the hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and for me, whenever I run bundle install, it installs two versions of bcrypt:

1. bcrypt-3.1.11
2. bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32

Therefore, If I just executed "**gem uninstall bcrypt**" and deleted the (2), then it worked fine.

To make sure it will not be installed again, I specify the platform on my Gemfile, like this:

```
gem 'bcrypt', platform: :ruby
```